# Reading from file returns a result I didn't expect, trying to understand why

Tags: c++, string, file-io, fstream

I have this code which contains a class and a main function:

```
class Employee {
    int m_id;
    string m_name;
    int m_age; public:
    Employee(int id, string name, int age) :m_id(id), m_name(name), m_age(age) {}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Employee& emp)
    {
        os << emp.m_id << " " << emp.m_name << " " << emp.m_age
           << endl;     
        return os;
    }
};

int main() {
    const int Emp_Num = 3;
    fstream fs("dataBase.txt", ios::out);
    if (!fs) {
        cerr << "Failed opening file. Aborting.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    Employee* list[Emp_Num] = 
        { new Employee(1234, "Avi", 34),
          new Employee(11111, "Beni", 24),
          new Employee(5621, "Reut", 26) };
    for (int i = 0; i < Emp_Num; i++) 
    {
        fs << (*list[i]);
        delete list[i];
    }
    fs.close();

    fs.open("dataBase.txt");
    if (!fs) {
        cerr << "Failed opening file. Aborting.\n";
        return -1;
    }
    fs.seekg(4);
    string strRead;
    fs >> strRead;
    cout << strRead << endl;
    fs.seekg(6, ios::cur);
    fs >> strRead;
    cout << strRead << endl;
    fs.seekg(-9, ios::end);
    fs >> strRead;
    cout << strRead << endl;
}
```

Here is how I understand it, after the first file open and close, the file `dataBase.txt` should look like this:

> 1234 Avi 34
>
> 11111 Beni 24
>
> 5621 Reut 26

My problem is with the reading and output to the console.
After I open the file, the pointer of my current position is at the first byte, which is the `1` before the `1234`.

I seek 4 from the beginning of the file,
so my pointer should be at (before) the space between the `1234` and `Avi`.

Now I get the next string into my string variable `strRead`,
now `strRead` contains "Avi" and the pointer should be between the `i` of `Avi` and the space after it.

Now i seek 6 from my current position,
by my count those are the 6 bytes i pass through:

1. `Space`
2. `3`
3. `4`
4. `Line break (return)`
5. `1`
6. `1`

So my pointer should be at the second line, after the two first ones.

I mean like this:

> 11|111 Beni 24

Now I get a string to `strRead`, by my understanding of the code `strRead` should now contain "111", instead, for some reason, it contains and output later "1111".

Could someone explain me why does it work that way?
There is no character between the first line drop and the first letter of the second line, so it should count as only 1 byte...

Comment: Just a thought - could there be a line break plus a carriage return? Try putting you string read / output in a loop, advancing one at a time, and see what it gives you.

Comment: @JackBeNimble i did a while loop, the output i get is all the possible strings, no breaks or spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following test:

I have run the second part of your code (which read from file) on a file with the text:

> 1234 Avi 34 11111 Beni 24 5621 Reut 26

So, I have replaced **end of lines** with **spaces**, and the code print to console output the expected result `111`. I then began to be suspicious about `seek` skipping end of lines.

Then I changed the code instead (without file modifications) and worked with the file in binary mode:

```
//...
fstream fs("dataBase.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
//...
fs.open("dataBase.txt",  ios::in | ios::binary );
//...
```

Again the result was the expected: `111`.

**What change in both cases?**

Well, in plain text (not in binary mode) the end of line are actually 2 chars (this can vary for other platforms, I'm reproducing this on Windows): `\r` and `\n`. Thats why you're reading four ones (`1111`) instead three (`111`).

Counting 6 positions from the space after `Avi`:

```
  A v i _ 3 4 \r \n 1 1 1 1 1
                    ^
        1 2 3  4  5 6 7 8
```

In the first test I performed, the a space (only one character) replaced two of them.

```
  A v i _ 3 4 _ 1 1 1 1 1
                  ^
        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

And in binary mode both of characters are represented as a single one unit to read(I don't have investigated if this is platform dependant).

```
A v i _ 3 4 B 1 1 1 1 1
                ^
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

B stands here for some binary code.

Comment: NOTE: `in plain text (not in binary mode) the end of line are actually 2 chars: \r and \n` - this is situationally specific. Is it perhaps better to note that "`text` mode will translate platform specific end-of-line character sequences into a standards conformant `\n`, while `binary` offers no such translation"? On unix, for example, your current statement is wrong: unix eol is '\n'.

Comment: @kfsone mmmm, yes, you're totally right, thats way I pointed out I have not investigated that in others platforms. You comment will be added to may answer. Thanks.

Comment: @kfsone, I not sure if in unix the end of line is just '\n' of what changes is the implementation of the C++ standar, that is instructed to read '\n' and '\r' as only one.  What would be?

Comment: The original Unix an C were developed hand-in-hand, so newline in both is '\n'. The standard end-of-line delimiter in C and C++ functions/libraries is '\n' (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/ "The delimiting character is the newline character ('\n') for the first form"). On older versions of MacOS it was '\r'. File operations performed in non-binary mode automatically translate for you. See http://goo.gl/iVtR7G - try the same code on windows.

Comment: @kfsone, thanks, it is a very good explanation, and very good references as well.